# Removing all occurrences of the specified substring, even overlapping ones

Tags: java, regex, string

For example, the source string is "appleappleapplebanana" and pattern I want to delete "appleapple".

I want it to delete all "appleapple" even if they overlap, so that only "banana" is left.

```
appleappleapplebanana
^^^^^^^^^^              <-first  occurrence
     ^^^^^^^^^^         <-second occurrence
```

If I use replaceAll, the result is "applebanana" since after deleting the first one, the remaining part is just "applebanana".

Expected results:

| Input | Pattern | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "appleapplebanana" | "appleapple" | "banana" |
| "appleapplebanana" | "appleapple" | "banana" |
| "appleappleapplebanana" | "appleapple" | "banana" |
| "applebanana" | "appleapple" | "applebanana" |
| "aaabbbaaabbbaaa" | "aaabbbaaa" | ""(empty string) |

I need to process arbitrary input patterns, so just using `replace("apple")` wouldn't work.

Though I have an idea for this:

1. Get all occurences (using something like KMP)
2. Mark corresponding characters as "to-be deleted"
3. Delete marked characters

However, I would like to know if there is a better (<s>fancier</s> ready made) way to achieve this.

**I ended up making my own function using the idea above, since no common libraries nor packages seems to support this feature.**

Comment: Just `.replace("apple", "")` will do. There is nothing overlapping here.

Comment: What's you tried?

Comment: If it is supposed to delete all substring why woudn't it delete all `"a"` or all `"p"`, or all `"pp"`?  What is the rule that `"apple"` is a valid substring that should be deleted but not `"a"`?

Comment: Thanks all for helping me. However the pattern isn't fixed, so I the suggestions wouldn't work in my case.

Comment: @markalex I am sure OP is overthinking it, I deduce it from the question wording. It can also be one of those cases when OP actually needs something totally different from what OP says.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, yes, I see it now)

Comment: Sounds like a [X/Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) to me. Because the solution to your problem is just `.replaceAll("apple", "");`

Comment: @markalex And now I think your suggestion was correct. Two or more consecutive occurrences of `apple`.

Comment: @markalex would you read part I just added? The program should not replace "apple" by itself. "applebanana" should remain "applebanana" after the process, since there is no "apple" in it. Also, I cannot just split the input into two parts since the pattern isn't fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, it will require converting string from repeated into regex `appleapple` -> `(?:apple){2,}`, `aaaa` -> `(?:a){4,}` and then replacing. I don't think this is better or "fancier" way. It is just plain simple over complication, IMO. Suggestion from question itself will be easier to maintain.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for your suggestion.The terminology "fancier" meant that making a helper function for things like just "replacing a pattern" isn't recommended, since it requires extra unit testing & performance evaluation due to company's rules. So I was just seeking for a java api that would allow me to do the same thing.

Also, for instance "aaabbbaaabbbaaa" should be "" when the remove-pattern is "aaabbbaaa", which makes it harder to generate a regex expression for it.

Maybe I'll just have to implement it myself :(

Comment: @Indefatigablex I'm still not sure why "remove any substring that is repeated" would result in turning "appleappleapplebanana" to "applebanana". Is there some minimum length required for the substrings to be replaced? Because otherwise replacing any repetition would give the end result of "aplebana" Because "p"  and "na" are substrings that are repeated as well in "applebanana"

Comment: @Indefatigablex, I don't believe there is something like this already available. You'll need to do wrapper of some kind for this. I recommend implementing solution based on your own description.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS "appleappleapplebanana" should be "banana". English isn't my first language, and seems like I failed to clarify what I wanted. The term "repeated" isn't that important, and just matching literally ALL occurrences is required. However thanks for your interest!

Comment: @markalex yup I ended up making my own function. I appreciate your help!

Comment: May the pattern length be used in the regex? E.g. [`.{1,10}(?<=appleapple)`](https://regex101.com/r/Yr8daE/2) where `10` will be the length of `appleapple`.

Comment: @bobblebubble, since you will need to dynamically create such regex anyway, I don't see any problem with using length. (OP might find such solution inappropriate for their situation with requirements, but at least from research stand point it will be interesting if you'll find a solution)

Comment: @Indefatigablex, feel free to provide your regex-free solution as an answer, since this question is reopened.

Comment: @bobblebubble, believe it worth the answer. At least for science. Also, you'll have a chance to explain why it works, because it might be not obvious on the first glance.

Comment: Technically, you're saying _"over-lapping"_, which would mean, _"appleappleappleappleapplebanana"_ is _"applebanana"_, and not _"banana"_.  What you're referring to would be called _"repeating"_.  To "overlap", means to _"cover partly"_.

Answer (score 2):

The question was a bit confusing at first. After the updates I think the best provided example to illustrate the problem is matching the "pattern" `aaabbbaaa` in `aaabbbaaabbbaaa`.

```
aaabbbaaabbbaaa
aaabbbaaa
      aaabbbaaa
      ^-^        < overlapping part
^-------------^  < match this part: 'aaa' is overlapping
```

If *length* of the "pattern"-string may be used in the regex, a [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) could be used:

```
.{1,9}(?<=aaabbbaaa)
```

[This regex (demo)](https://regex101.com/r/7c5W8Q/4) will match from one to the strings length characters as long as `aaabbbaaa` is behind. So that will match `aaabbbaaa` but also `bbbaaa` because the last `a` is also preceded by `aaabbbaaa` and due to the length restriction it will not skip over any other substring. It will also [match *non-overlaps* in `aaabbbaaaaaabbbaaa`](https://regex101.com/r/7c5W8Q/2) but [leave e.g. `ccc` in `aaabbbaaacccaaabbbaaa`](https://regex101.com/r/7c5W8Q/3).

[A Java demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##lVHLbsMgELz7K1acsJoi9ewmVT8gUqUe2x7WDnJIMUaAo1ZRvt1dA0mdPqRW2LCzzMAsu8M9Xu82r@OoOtu7ADtKiCEoLZxs5ZtYY2i20lXFL/sPGIJ0pioKO9RaNdBo9B7WqExxKAB8wEDZfa82FDtlH4Pj9CvTTngBObYYSqJPEjjl4g2wBCYONwsGVxNJaGnasOUlQXbkd7fLvDHhklVRn02BJXGORdN3VmnJ46FldXmPH3QgrhVdKpeTtZIqtBobea81Z4wkSfPug@xEPwRhSR204TEPwHw6brmimOwQnEw9GwInis3OiDPzfUHJVa8gnZLgd1KyvDqRIkysyIkVHifLuS/zRnTUndyEpxdA1/rPtz83iaG1WsapRkODLWCWY/kNf@L/V/RHKmJd1@c50s/gG7tGRx@NHMyXSfolk9/rOI4f) with incorporating the length:

```
String regex = ".{1," + pat.length() + "}(?<=" + pat + ")";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
String result = p.matcher(str).replaceAll("");
```

*Update including parts of [@markalex idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76383244/removing-all-occurrences-of-the-specified-substring-even-overlapping-ones/76395681#comment134718303_76395681)*: For better performance, especially with longer inputs first match the "pattern" once and wrap the lookbehind part into a repeated group ([regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/7g7WRL/3)).

```
aaabbbaaa(?:.{1,9}(?<=aaabbbaaa))*
```

This will also lead to getting one match for the adjacent parts which might be desired anyways. Further you can use [`\w` (word character)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) instead of the dot if input contains non-word characters.

Comment: Will [`((?=aaabbbaaa).{1,9})*aaabbbaaa`](https://regex101.com/r/XWoRrv/1) do the same trick?

Comment: @markalex Very nice, yes I think so! It looks to be a bit less efficient though (at least in the PCRE steps counter on regex 101 [if you compare it](https://regex101.com/r/30DPuW/1) to [the lookbehind version](https://regex101.com/r/30DPuW/2). But **mixing our ideas** together, we could reassemble an even more efficient: [`aaabbbaaa(?:.{1,9}(?<=aaabbbaaa))*`](https://regex101.com/r/30DPuW/3)  Certainly yours is a working option for regex flavors that don't support lookbehind, thank you.

Comment: @bobblebubble, this is very nice detailed answer, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, this is over-lapping.

```
appleapple
     appleappleappleapple
                    appleapple
```

And, this is repeating.

```
appleapple
     appleapple
          appleapple
```

Although, you could refer to the latter as, *having over-lapped*.
Which, intrinsically, is not a property of a pattern that is considered to have a repeating quality.
It would be inherent at that point—redundant—it's just a description.

In addition to *String#replace* there is also *[String#replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String))*.
It uses a *[regular expression pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)* as the first argument.

You could use the following pattern to replace repeating values that have over-lapped.

```
(apple)\1+
```

```java
replaceAll("(apple)\\1+", "")
```

I'm not sure if there is a way to remove *over-lapping* values using a single pattern.
I imagine it would be much more complex.

You mentioned *"... mark corresponding characters as 'to-be deleted'"*.
This would most likely be the logical way to remove truly over-lapping values.

Comment: Read the question closely, specifically explanation for first example. Do you see removing of "repetition" there? I personally don't.

Comment: And regarding removing overlapping pattern with a single regex: if you'll read comments by bobble under question, you'll regex, that will allow removing of overlapping pattern in a single expression.

Comment: @markalex, _"read the question closely, specifically explanation for first example."_, I don't understand what you're saying.  It sounds condescending, and comical.  Should I put my glasses on, also?

Comment: My first comment is about the fact, that pattern `appleapple` in `appleappleapplebanana` can be found two times, and those are overlapping. It hardly can be classified as a repetition. Sorry if it was a bit harsh, I was just a tad dumbfounded but answer, that critiqued OP, rather commonly known method names and (I assume) an advise how to solve original problem, that failed on the first provided by question example.

Comment: Regarding your edit: it is valid way to solve questions problem, and something similar was discussed in comments. But task of converting arbitrary input string like `appleapple` to `(apple)\1+`, and `aba` to `((a)(b))+\2` or `(ab)+a` is not obvious and requires additional explanation.